# Possible bug in the filer-tag list / tag search box

Tags: bug, tags, tag-search

While selecting the comparatively *longer* tag names for the filter tag list (tag-search box), the tag name is "distorted".

<sup>(*Can anyone suggest a better wording? My English vocabulary is not so good*).</sup>

Steps to reproduce:

1. Go to [Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions)
2. Select "Custom tags" as the filer value
3. key-in "apache-commins-col" and wait for the tag suggestion to appear. (for [apache-commons-collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-commons-collection))
4. Hover your mouse over the suggested tag (Don't click)

It should resemble the below scenario

[image: problematic tag suggestion name]

Maybe not in high-priority, but can we get this fixed?

---

Browser: Chrome 43+
OS     : Windows 7.